# Witcher 2 won't start

Tags: steam, the-witcher-2

When I try launch Witcher 2, it gives me an error that says "Failed to start game (missing executable). I've tried verifying the game cache.

Comment: It might be your antivirus program not allowing it to run. Try turning off your antivirus (temporarily) or running the launcher as  Administrator.

Comment: Navigate to the folder that should contain the executable (C:\Programs\Steam\steamapps\common\Witcher 2) and check if it actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently moved my OS to a new SSD and as a result, the steam folder stayed behind on my old 2TB SATA drive. Many games worked, but quite a few gave me the same error. I searched high and low for a solution after moving folders about and installing Steam as described on a number of sites. Ultimately, the only fix was to *uninstall the game through steam, then reinstall it.*

The best part of this is that because Steam isn't actually sure where the game is, (thus the missing executable error, despite plainly being able to find it when I manually browse to the folder) is that the game data isn't actually deleted. I then reinstalled the games, and it would claim that it had downloaded the full game in just minutes - it actually appeared to discover the game files, check them and then work fine. I will say that this was the case for almost all of my games, with the exception of I believe one of the Batman: Arkham games, which actually did spend an hour downloading ~7GB or whatever it is.

*Verifying the game cache did not work - as Steam appeared to be looking in the wrong place for the game.*

Answer (score -2):

- Let your antivirus allow the game/turn it off
- Reinstall the game

Maybe something went wrong when downloading the file? Check if there is a .exe and try running it? 
Maybe redownload if that doesn't work.